# Head bolt torque settings for Daewoo Matiz 800cc 2004/5

Tags: cylinder-head, daewoo

I'm looking for the Head bolt torque settings for Daewoo Matiz 800cc 2004/5. My research yielded 85--90 NSm from [here](http://www.fixya.com/cars/t26239097-torque_setting_cherv_spark_800cc_3), but it does not seem correct. Another site stated 65-70Nm.

Any suggestions on what the actual value are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

65-70Nm (48-52ft lb) - As seen in the workshop manual for that engine, here https://www.autocats.ws/manual/chevrolet/tis0808/EN/documents_2006/Matiz/sm-m/6M2_1B12.en.html#M1B1CHG. Note also the tightening order, as per this image from that site; [image]